# How to process KEY_HOME and KEY_END reliably under ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

I am struggling to have ncurses generate KEY_HOME or KEY_END events, instead the raw escape sequence is coming through as a sequence of characters.

The following simple C program illustrates the problem:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700

#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>

void clean(void)
{
        echo();
        nl();
        nocbreak();
        endwin();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

        initscr();
        cbreak();
        nonl();
        noecho();

        atexit(clean);

        keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

        clear();
        refresh();

        int ch = getch();

        if (ch == ERR)
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "getch");

        warnx("read: %x", ch);
        halfdelay(1);

        while((ch = getch()) != ERR)
        {
                warnx("read: %x", ch);
        }

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compile with -lncurses, and redirect stderr to a log file.
When pressing HOME:

```
test: read: 1b
test: read: 5b
test: read: 31
test: read: 7e
```

When pressing UP

```
test: read: 103
```

How come HOME and END (and indeed F1 etc.) are not parsed by ncurses into KEY_HOME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have set **`TERM`** to a value which does not match the terminal's behavior.  For instance, the **`linux`** terminal description has [**`khome=\E[1~`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-basic) (which corresponds to the example output), while **`xterm`** has [**`khome=\E[OH`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm_app).  You can see this using

```
infocmp linux xterm | grep khome
```

If the terminal description does not match the actual behavior, ncurses will not match the incoming bytes, and will behave as shown.

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. I am using Putty as a client, with TERM set to xterm-256color. If I change that to screen-256color my code works (I do seem to recall some things didn't work with screen-256color but there we go)